# Can't get Selenium tests to run in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, selenium, internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

We have been successfully using Selenium tests on Chrome and Firefox, we now want to start testing on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine with Internet Explorer too. We are so far now that the tests start, and Internet Explorer opens and goes to the page we want to test. But any interactions with the page fail the test, it doesn't find any of the elements. The error is usually 'element cannot be found by xpath'. The same tests run fine in Chrome and Firefox on the same machine.

Comment: Set some wait time before interaction with element. IE might be responding slow, so provide some wait time before that particular element and check

Answer (score 0):

Here are few checklist to execute through Internet Explorer:

1. Ensure that you are using the latest Selenium 3.x jars along with IE 11.
2. Next you need to download the "IEDriverServer" (32 bit) from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0.zip).
3. Provide the absolute path of the "IEDriverServer" while setting the system property.
4. Here is the code for IE 11 to open gmail and login with valid credentials:

(replace your_id with a valid userid & replace your_password with a valid password)

```
    //Internet Explorer 11
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http:\\\\gmail.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("your_id");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("your_password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    driver.quit();
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. The problem was that I needed to turn off protected mode for all security zones in internet explorer -> internet settings -> security.